Judaism’s philosophy of time
What is Judaism’s perspective on the philosophy of time? Is Judaism presentist or eternalist? Furthermore, is there a discussion about how rituals/mitzvot exist in relation to time within Jewish tradition?

It is both, depending on the point of view G-d vs. human. Also time is relative: sin extends exile and stretches the time, teshuvah shortens exile. The 6000 years is time for atonement for Adam's sin. It can be shorter. Finally, teshuvah allows one to travel back in time and erase past sins and maybe turn them to merits.

This will likely answer most of your questions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXpQ_3bAPFQ

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/74335/jewish/What-Is-Time.htm

may be of interest - https://mosaicapress.com/product/the-time-of-your-life/

See the uncensored version of Kovetz Yesodos Vachakiros for a discussion of the topic. I haven't seen it discussed anywhere else.
